# Python Vlookup and have result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to a Vlookup using python the issue is that I need my output to be formatted a certain way.
Here are an extract of my excels:
A.xlsx

| Account | ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1174 | 4137 |  | 06/09/2022 |
| 1174 | 4610 |  | 12/09/2022 |
| 1174 | 4245 |  | 18/09/2022 |

B.xlsx

| Date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 20220911 | 4137 |
| 20220916 | 4610 |
| 20220918 | 4985 |

I would like to do a Vlookup on the ID columns and to have the output in a seperate column. If there is a match I get an "Ok" if I don't I get a "KO"
It should look that way:

| Account | ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1174 | 4137 | OK | 06/09/2022 |
| 1174 | 4610 | OK | 12/09/2022 |
| 1174 | 4245 | KO | 18/09/2022 |

or

| Account | ID | ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1174 | 4137 | 4137 | OK | 06/09/2022 |
| 1174 | 4610 | 4610 | OK | 12/09/2022 |
| 1174 | 4245 | Null | KO | 18/09/2022 |

I wrote that, but I'm not sure how to go from there and get my desired output:

````
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as opxl

initial_workbook = 'A.xlsx'
info_workbook = 'B.xlsx'
output_workbook ='outbook.xlsx'

df_initial = pd.read_excel(initial_workbook)
df_info = pd.read_excel (info_workbook)

df_initial.columns = (df_initial.columns.str.strip().str.upper()
            .str.replace(' ', '_')
            .str.replace('(', '')
            .str.replace(')', ''))


df_3 = pd.merge(df_initial, df_info,on=['ID','ID'])


df_3.to_excel(output_workbook, index=False)```

Thank you,
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) Be sure to convert Date columns for each df appropriately.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data1 = {
    'Account': {0: 1174, 1: 1174, 2: 1174},
    'ID': {0: 4137, 1: 4610, 2: 4245},
    'Status': {0: np.NAN, 1: np.NAN, 2: np.NAN},
    'Date': {0: '06/09/2022', 1: '12/09/2022', 2: '18/09/2022'}
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"], dayfirst=True)
print(f"{df1}\n")

   Account    ID  Status       Date
0     1174  4137     NaN 2022-09-06
1     1174  4610     NaN 2022-09-12
2     1174  4245     NaN 2022-09-18
```

2nd df

```
data2 = {
    'Date': {0: 20220911, 1: 20220916, 2: 20220918},
    'ID': {0: 4137, 1: 4610, 2: 4985}
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"], format="%Y%m%d")
print(f"{df2}\n")

        Date    ID
0 2022-09-11  4137
1 2022-09-16  4610
2 2022-09-18  4985
```

Final df

```
df = (
    pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["ID", "ID"], how="left", suffixes=("", "_df2"))
    .fillna("")
)

df = df.replace({pd.NaT: "no_match"})
df["Status"] = np.where(df["Date_df2"].eq("no_match"), "KO", "OK")
df = df.drop(columns="Date_df2")
print(df)

   Account    ID Status       Date
0     1174  4137     OK 2022-09-06
1     1174  4610     OK 2022-09-12
2     1174  4245     KO 2022-09-18
```

Comment: I tried it, but I have encountered two issues I have a lot of duplicates but also the status columns only returns "Ok" no KO